# JS Rounding 3 decimal points to 2 decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Math.round(num * 100) / 100
```

Case 1:

```
15.625 * 19 = 296.875
```

When we apply the code above, the final result is 296.88 which is **correct**.

```
var test = 15.625 * 19;
test = Math.round(test * 100) / 100;
console.log( test ); // Return 296.88 (Correct)
```

Case 2:

```
15.225 * 19 = 289.275
```

When we apply the code above, the final result is 289.27 which is **not correct**.

```
var test = 15.225 * 19;
test = Math.round(test * 100) / 100;
console.log( test ); // Return 289.27 (Not correct)
```

Hence, I tried to breakdown and found out that:

```
289.275 * 100 = 28927.499999999996
Math.round(28927.499999999996) = 28927
Then, 28927/100 = 289.27
```

The suppose to be 0.5 turned into 0.499999999996 after multiply by 100

(^ This is the part I'm stuck and not sure how to proceed)

For temporary usage, I did something like this as below:

```
var compiledPrice = 289.275;
console.log( 'compiledPrice1 : ' + compiledPrice );
// 289.275

compiledPrice = compiledPrice * 10;
console.log( 'compiledPrice2 : ' + compiledPrice );
// 2892.75

compiledPrice = compiledPrice.toFixed(1);
console.log( 'compiledPrice3 : ' + compiledPrice );
// 2892.8

compiledPrice = compiledPrice / 10;
console.log( 'compiledPrice4 : ' + compiledPrice );
// 289.28000000000003

compiledPrice = compiledPrice.toFixed(2);
console.log( 'compiledPrice5 : ' + compiledPrice );
// 289.28
```

I'm not sure is this the proper way to solve this issue, I hope somebody would able to shed some light to me please.

Comment: how about `+Intl.NumberFormat('en', {useGrouping: false, maximumFractionDigits: 2}).format(289.275)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round to at most 2 decimal places, if necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/how-to-round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-if-necessary)

Comment: @NguyễnNgọcHùngLong Before I posted this question, I was using that solution for quite a while until I have this rounding issue with "289.275"
var test = Math.round((289.275 + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100
The above method will return "289.275", by right should be "289.28"

Comment: Hi @ProGu, I tested your method and it works! Tested on 289.270, 289.271, 289.272... until 289.279 all rounded to 2 decimal places like wanted, and shorter solution compared to my temporary hack. If I hit any issues I'll update here for everyone's benefit, but so far so good as for now :)
```
var test = Intl.NumberFormat('en', {useGrouping: false, maximumFractionDigits: 2}).format(289.275)
console.log( test );
// Return 289.28
```